# Can ajax insertions be performed in correct order without using async:false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

On my ASP.Net MVC page I have a AJAX form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "target"
    }))
    {
            //form in here
            <input name="foo">
            //...
    }
```

Users can either enter their data and submit the form manually, or copy larger amounts of data, and submit it all at once. I use the following JS to do this.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
var objects = getDataFromClipboard();
for (x = 0; x < objects.length; x++) {
    $('#foo').val(objects[x]);
    $('#form').submit();
}
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

The issue is that I'm forced to use "async: false" which is very slow and freezes my entire page while it's working. If I leave "async: true" then the results are appended in the incorrect order.

**Is there some faster way to force those forms to perform their updates in order?**

Comment: Two possibilities; First, chain the requests. Second, put all the data in a single request and send that. The latter is by far the best option here. Ignore anyone who suggests `async: false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My controller/model which are processing the input are set up to work with single values (strings). Can I still send all the data in one request, or do I need to rewrite those to accept/return arrays?

Comment: Yes, you will need to rewrite the models for those endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've changed everything so the data is sent in a single request, and it performs way better, and doesn't freeze my page. I've posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rory McCrossan for pointing me in the right direction.

A pretty simple solution is to group all my input as one string, split by a separator. Then I can simply send the entire data in one request. I only had to rewrite my controller to handle this input.

I changed my JS as follows:

```
var objects = getDataFromClipboard();
var foo = objects[0];
for (x = 1; x < objects.length; x++) {
    foo = foo + "|" + objects[x];
}
$('#foo').val(foo);
$('#form').submit();
```

My form and model remained unchanged.

Model

```
public class FooModel
{
    public String foo { get; set; }
}
```

Form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions {
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "target"
}))
{
        //form in here
        <input name="foo">
        //...
}
```

My controller now handles the input as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult action(ADModel model)
{
    char separator = "|"[0];
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.foo))
    {
        string[] foos = model.fname.Split(separator);
        string result = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < foos.Length; x++)
        {
            result = result + searchData(foo[x]) + "<br>";
        }
        return Content(result, "text/html");
    } else {
        return Content("<i>No results found</i>","text/html");
    }
}
```